# Loop for hidden folderes in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cmd

How can I loop through all hidden folders, in windows-cmd?

This code

```
FOR /D %i IN (*) DO @echo %i
```

handles only non-hidden folders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To loop through all folder in a directory (including hidden folders) in cmd you can use:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN ('DIR /A:D /b') do @echo %i
```

You can exclude system folder using:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN ('DIR /A:D-S /b') do @echo %i
```

And if you want to get subfolders (you might not want to this in a folder with many subfolders) :

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN ('DIR /A:D /s /b') do @echo %i
```