# Windows CMD or BATCH file that "flags" empty folders (and folders that only contain empty folders)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filesystems

Most companies I have worked for start new projects with a templated folder structure. Windows will automatically flag empty folders (the icon shown in the file explorer is that of an empty folder) however, folders whose subfolders are also empty will not be flagged (their icon shows a folder containing files). This can create confusion and lead to mistakes during the early stages of a project as it would appear at a glance that some folders have had their content added when they really only contain empty subfolders.

So my question is:

> How can I iterate over folders with empty subfolders and "flag" them via the use of a Batch file.

The .bat file would need to search through subfolders to determine if a folder has any real content. If the folder does not have real content then the .bat file would need to flag it (flagging could be done with a change of its icon or filename). This would make it much easier to navigate new projects with large templated folder structures.

I don't need a completed file, I would just like to know how it could be achieved. However, any tips or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality would be more than welcome!

*Edit

Just to clarify I will show an example:
If I create an empty folder called 'Project' it will display with the *Empty Folder* icon. As shown Below:

[image]

Now I will add a new folder to my project folder called 'I am Empty':

[image]

The folder 'Project' no longer displays with the *Empty Folder* icon. It now uses the icon that shows it with content. As shown Below:

[image]

What I want is a .bat file that will parse the contents of the 'Project' folder and determine that it only contains the 'I am Empty' folder, which is empty and "flag" that folder (to flag it we could change the icon of the 'Project' folder back to the *Empty Folder* icon, change the name or "gray it out"). As shown Below:

[image]

Comment: *"Windows will automatically flag empty folders"* - I don't understand, what you are trying to say here. When I create an empty folder, Windows doesn't do anything about it. It's just another folder in the file system.

Comment: Right, I want to flag folders who contain empty folder...

Comment: If PowerShell is an option, you could make your life a lot easier (see [Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week: Finding All the Empty Folders in a Directory Tree](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730953.aspx)). I still don't quite get, what you mean by *"flag"*. Might make your question clearer, if you explained that a bit better. Or leave it out altogether, since that's unrelated to your question: Identifying all empty directories.

Comment: I just added some examples that demonstrated the problem better than words alone. Also, in my original question I state: (flagging could be done with a change of its icon or filename). Thus if changing the icon is not possible. I would also be ok with the .bat file renaming the folder from 'Project' to 'Project(empty)'.

Comment: What you called *"flagging"* and attributed to Windows is really a feature of File Explorer's Details pane. It is neither related to Windows nor a property assigned to a directory, or one that you could assign to a folder. If you want to customize the display of Explorer, a .bat file won't do. You'd have to implement a shell extension (I **think** a [Preview Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144143.aspx), but I'm not entirely sure about that).

Comment: I understand that icon shown when the file is empty vs not-empty is controlled without changing an attribute of the file itself. What I am looking for is a way to manually override what the File Explorer is doing "Auto-Magically" and change the folder's icon attribute based on the rules I defined in my question. It would appear as though Stephan has given me a pretty good starting point! Thank you for your help.

Comment: The icon shown in the Details Pane of File Explorer is a lot more involved than just an empty/non-empty directory. For example, it also indicates, whether there is only a single or multiple files in a directory. Or if there is a file in a sub-directory of the current directory. The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36407145/1889329) is of no help: It is written in a language you cannot easily use when writing a shell extension.

Comment: @IInspectable: Kenneth said: "(flagging could be done with a change of its icon _or filename_)", so my `ren` option technically answers his question. (for example `ren "%%i" "Empty-%%i"`)

Comment: @Stephan: Your answer does meet the requirements as stated in the question. I don't think going this route is very helpful, though: You'd have to run the script over and over again, each time you navigate the directory tree. And there's nothing that changes renamed folders back to their original folder names, once files start to show up. A shell extension would always show up-to-date information, without user intervention.

Comment: You didn't say anything about renaming them back. Although it's quite trivial: `for /d %%i in (empty-*) do ...` You could set up a scheduled task to run every few minutes (not quite realtime, but might be sufficient). If you want more, look for other options than batch.

Comment: I noticed that this question received a down vote. Is there anything I can do to fix this question so that it is more useful to the community? What specifically is difficult to understand, or is misleading? I researched this question intensively and found very little on stack overflow to help. What I needed was Stephan's DIR /a-d trick that runs the desired code on failure. That solution is genius!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the answer given by Stephan and looking at other related stack exchange posts I pieced this solution together and it works well for my needs:

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "%~dp0"
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%F in ('dir /b/s/ad  *') DO (
    @dir /s /a-d-s "%%F">nul 2>&1|| ATTRIB +H "%%F"
    @dir /s /a-d-s "%%F">nul 2>&1&& ATTRIB -H "%%F"
)
POPD 
EXIT
```

I opted for a solution that did not modify file names. While testing that approach I realized it doesn't create the best user experience.

Instead, running this batch file hides the folders that are effectively empty and if your folder settings allow you to see hidden folders then they appear faded out. It also re-shows hidden files that have new content since the last time the batch file was ran.

For those of you coming to this solution who, like myself, are relatively inexperienced with batch scripting. I will explain what the code does and why (as I understand it).

I don't want to change the batch file for each implementation so I call `PUSHD "%~dp0` to set the active directory to the folder containing the batch file (this lets me include the batch file in the folder-structure template, which is copied and pasted for each project)

Since I decided to use the hidden attribute for folder flagging, I needed to modify the `FOR` loop . `FOR` loops typically ignore hidden files which becomes troublesome if you need show a file that was previously hidden because it has new content. Running `FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%F in ('dir /b/s/ad  *') DO ()`
allows the batch file to loop through all files mainly because of the /f attribute, but check out
[this post about looping through hidden folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305011/loop-for-hidden-folderes-in-windows) for more information.

Inside the for loop I am pretty much doing what Stephen suggested in his answer with the added logic to remove the hidden attribute on folders that no longer need it.

The only thing this batch file is lacking, is the ability to auto update on folder modifications or to auto-run on folder open (I hear this might be possible with an .ini file?) however, for my needs it will suffice to rerun the batch file, manually, after making changes to the folder.

Batch scripting is way outside of my comfort zone as far as scripting languages go so please forgive and correct me if I have made any mistakes or if there is a more reliable way to do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd example
for /d %%i in (*) do @dir /b /s /a-d "%%i">nul 2>&1|| @echo "%%i" has no files
```

give `for` an additional `/r` if you want to check subfolders too.

The trick is to list files only (`/a-d`) in the folder and all subfolders (`/s`) and if this fails (`||`) (because there are no files), do something with this folder (just `echo` here, but `rd /s /q` or `ren` is also possible)